# Is it possible to multiple updates across rows based on a query on single pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update a dataframe of country names in one go

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'countries': ['United States of America','United Kingdom','Republic of Korea','Netherlands']})
df
```

Output 1:

[image: Output 1:]

I would like country names updated and it seems inefficient to do it as below

```
df.loc[df['countries']=='United States of America' ,'countries'] = 'USA'
df.loc[df['countries']=='United Kingdom' ,'countries'] = 'UK'
df.loc[df['countries']=='Republic of Korea' ,'countries'] = 'South Korea'
df.loc[df['countries']=='Netherlands' ,'countries'] = 'Holland'

df
```

The above works to give me this output:

[image: Output 2:]

I'd ideally like to update this with something on the lines of:

```
df.loc[df['countries'] in ['United States of America','United Kingdom','Republic of Korea','Netherlands'] 
       ,'countries'] = ['USA','UK','South Korea','Holland']
```

However, I am presented with this error and I am not able to get past it by attempting to use `.any()` function or anything else I've tried so far.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Would appreciate any help to try and make this more efficient to update multiple ordered qualifications with a corresponding list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary with `pd.DataFrame.replace`:

```
dd = {'United States of America':'USA', 
      'United Kingdom':'UK',
      'Republic of Korea':'South Korea',
      'Netherlands':'Holland'}

df.replace(dd)
```

Output:

```
     countries
0          USA
1           UK
2  South Korea
3      Holland
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Scott. Worked beautifully ! I had to place the inplace=True flag additionally to ensure it updates the original dataframe.

Comment: or reassign to df = df.replace(dd) Either way.  Happy coding @AnilMenon!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas.Series.map`

```
df['countries'] = df['countries'].fillna("").map(
    {"United States of America": "US", "United Kingdom": "UK"...}
)
```

output,

```
     countries
0           US
1           UK
2  South Korea
3      Holland
```

Comment: You can obviously also define the dictionary first like dict1 = {'United States of America': 'US','United Kingdom':'UK','Republic of Korea':'South Korea'} then use that inside the map

Comment: Good solution.  Only concern is that if the whole dataframe has ,say , 180 countries and I run map on the 2 countries , the rest are returned in the new df as NaN

Comment: Yes, it replaces with NaN for keys not defined in the map.

Comment: you would need to use fillna with the existing series for this to work..